# varnish vcl 4 - If statuscode is 302 and its a picture, pass in vcl_recv somehow

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I cant seem to figure out how I can tell Varnish to NOT cache images which return 302.

The case is this:
I have an image handler that resizes on the fly. I call a URL - it resize the image and then redirect to the new image.

At the moment my iages are not returned via varnish. It goes into a constanct loop of redirects because of the caching. Really need to avoid this.

Any solutions?

Comment: I'm curious about the infinite redirects. If the 302 is to a new URL, shouldn't it serve and not redirect again? Is the resized image actually served via the original URL?

Comment: Hi, it ends up in a loop, which I avoided by saying in backend_response that images had a TTL of 0 in case of 302

Comment: When you say "this case" it is still not clear if the URL is changing or not. If the URL is not changing (but that sometimes it sends TTL 0 and sometimes not) then it seems you could still end up in a situation with an incorrect cache.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know in vcl_recv if the request will end up in a 302 or 200 or else. I think the Best is to override the cache in vcl_backend_response in the case of 302 status with image request.

Comment: Hi I ended up doing a TTL for images, and set to 0 in case of this.